# Order by file type in Visual Studio quick switch between tabs window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This might not be a valid question but here it goes.

**Scenario:**

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

At a given time I have about 15-20 files opened in Visual Studio and switch between them frequently.

**Difficulty**:

I am finding it hard to locate a **tab/file** from the small window when I press `Ctrl+Tab` since it's ordered **alphabetically**.

**Needed Solution:**

If the list can be altered to **Sort by file type** rather than **Sort by file name** I can locate the file easier.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Tabs Studio (my commercial add-in) can help to work with lots of opened files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio power tools provide a functionality to pin tabs, maybe you can use that functionality to quickly navigate between your required tabs, which can be displayed on a seperate row as well.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/10/document-well-2010-plus.aspx#pinnedtabsseparate

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Tab Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com)'s [Sorter Add-in](http://www.tabsstudio.com/documentation/addins/sorter.html) to sort your tabs by extension, this just sorts the tab headers not the Ctrl+Tab view but given Tab Studio displays all you tab headers at the same time it may be what you are after.  The down side is $49, you can trial it to see if it would work for you.

My tab headers look like this:
[image: Tab Headers]

With these Sorter options:
[image: Sort By Extension options]

Of course you could add further rules to sort within the extension sets.

Answer (score -1):

Better keep the maximum five or seven files in a tab.. Don't put 10 or 15 files in a tab. There has no option to sort the list in tab.